# How are input values passed to dynamic Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

Background:  I'm trying to create a dynamic filter where the user may specify multiple attributes and corresponding attribute values to filter a component list.  The component that is dynamically added consists of 2 drop-downs; one for the attribute selection, another for the attribute values and an add button to dynamically add the next attribute filter component.  The attribute list is filtered by a selected catalog which is passed through an @Input.  The pieces look something like this:

In a parent HTML doc, the attribute filter container is included.

```
<app-attribute-filter-container [catalogSelected]="catalog" ></app-attribute-filter-container>
```

The attribute filter container currently consists of an ng-template with a dynamic placeholder

```
<ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
```

The corresponding typescript for the container:

```
import { Component, NgModule, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AttributeFilterCreatorService } from '../../services/attribute-filter-creator.service';
import { Catalog } from '../../interfaces/interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-attribute-filter-container',
  templateUrl: './attribute-filter-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./attribute-filter-container.component.css'],
  providers: [AttributeFilterCreatorService]
})

export class AttributeFilterContainerComponent {
  @Input() catalogSelected: Catalog;
  service: AttributeFilterCreatorService;

  @ViewChild('dynamic', {
    read: ViewContainerRef
  }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef

  constructor(@Inject(AttributeFilterCreatorService) service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Container Catalog: ', this.catalogSelected);
    this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
    this.service.addDynamicComponent();
  }

}
```

And lastly, the typescript for the attribute filter component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Attribute, AttributeValue, Catalog } from '../../interfaces/interfaces';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-attribute-filter',
  templateUrl: './attribute-filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./attribute-filter.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AttributeFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() catalogSelected: Catalog;
  @Input() attributes: Attribute[];
  attributeValues: AttributeValue[];
  urlBase: string = "";
  selectedAttribute: Attribute;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.urlBase = baseUrl;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.attributes) {
      this.LoadAttributes();
    }
  }

  attributeSelect(selectedAttribute) {
    this.LoadAttributeValues(selectedAttribute.id);
  }

  private LoadAttributes() {
    var attUrl = this.urlBase + 'api/Attribute/Attributes/' + this.catalogSelected.catalogcode;

    console.log("LOAD ATTRIBUTES", attUrl);

    this.http.get<Attribute[]>(attUrl).subscribe(result => {
      if (result.length == 0) {
        this.auth.logout();
        this.router.navigate(["login"]);
      }
      else {
        this.attributes = result;
      }

    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

  private LoadAttributeValues(attributeid) {
    this.attributeValues = [];

    var attValUrl = this.urlBase + 'api/Attribute/AttributeValues/' + this.catalogSelected.catalogcode + '/' + attributeid;

    this.http.get<AttributeValue[]>(attValUrl).subscribe(result => {
      if (result.length == 0) {
        this.auth.logout();
        this.router.navigate(["login"]);
      }
      else {
        this.attributeValues = result;
      }

    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

}
```

The **catalogSelected** value never makes it in to the dynamically injected component.  This causes the values for the attribute drop-down to never be loaded.

Answer (score -1):

If by dynamic you mean entryComponents. So you cannot pass inputs to them. instead you can use a bidirectional service communication to pass data.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Yes, entryComponents.

Comment: ya so you cannot pass input. follow the link i gave.